# IgnoreRoute in ASP.MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-routing, ignoreroute

I am trying to access a .js file in the views directory.
I have an MVC application with /Views/Home/MyControl.ascx
I have a js file /Views/Home/MyControl.js

I wish to reference the .js file and keep it with the control.
I have tried the following entries in the routing, and none seem to work.

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.js");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.js/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{controller}/{resource}.js/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{*alljs}", new { alljs = @".*\.js(/.*)?" });
```

Please help, please don't suggest adding the .js file to the scripts directory.
I would like to make it work this way, or know why it cannot be done.

I would put the script into the page, only script debugging is broken in VS2010 B2.

Thanks
Regards
Craig.

Comment: You're simply just doing it wrong if you don't want to place your scripts in the scripts folder, unless you can explain why you want to differ from that standard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Views` folder is, well for views, and javascript should be put elsewhere. That's why the designers of the MVC framework put a `web.config` in this `Views` folder that denies access to any file inside. You could modify this defaut setting but be warned that this could be a potential security hole. So open the `web.config` file located in the `Views` folder and:

Replace:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

with:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="*.aspx" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
  <add path="*.master" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
  <add path="*.ascx" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Navigate to `http://yoursite/Views/test.js`

P.S. You could also remove all the `IgnoreRoutes` you put in `global.asax`.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
This does sound wrong. 
What if I put the javascript with the controller, would that be a better approach. I don't really want it in the general scripts folder. Would I need the IgnoreRoute for that to work?

Comment: I know this is an old post, but holy crap this just helped me after 4+ hours of tearing my hair out. I wish I could upvote this 20 times!

Answer (score 6):

Wouldn't this be a better solution using the DefaultHttpHandler
for html resources and keeping the HttpNotFoundHandler for all other types of file

```
<httpHandlers>  
  <add path="*.html" verb="*" type="System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler"/> 
  <add path="*.*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/> 
</httpHandlers>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually for IIS integrated mode, you need to use `System.Web.StaticHttpHandler`:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="*.css" verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticHttpHandler"/> 
  <add path="*.js" verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticHttpHandler"/> 
  <add path="*.*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/> 
</httpHandlers>
```

Apparently `System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler` works in IIS classic mode only.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC 4 I had to update the handler section as well as the httpHandlers section.

I updated the web.config in the Views folder with the following.

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="*.aspx" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
  <add path="*.cshtml" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>

<handlers>
  <remove name="BlockViewHandler" />
  <add name="BlockViewHandlerRazor" path="*.cshtml" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
  <add name="BlockViewHandlerAspx" path="*.aspx" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
</handlers>
```